# Same code in CSS giving different results in 2 positions on same page

Tags: html, css

Wondering why same code giving 2 different results on webpage. I have pasted the link to my code as well below as well as the extract which causing confusion. `#video` gives centralized content whereas `#table` gives left-aligned content.

```
#video{ 
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:1600px;
    padding:10px;
    opacity:0.7;
}

#table {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:700px;

}
```

Code [link](https://codepen.io/Donnie-D/pen/gmmwyR)

Comment: You can include jsfiddles right here in your question. There is a convenient button in SO's editor.

Answer (score 1):

Given the css classes you have, #table corresponds a div that contains the table. Divs inherently, has the width of 100% and are displayed block. You specified the table width as 700% (BTW, they are somehow block and clear all surrounding elements). So if you have a display:block or display:table and you want to centralize it horizontally, the best option would be to set the left and right margin to auto.

Therefore, add this to your css classes:

```
 #table table{
      margin:auto
}
```

Which basically means all tables inside the element carrying the id of "table" should have the margin value of "auto".

Comment: this is correct, but you haven't explained why it is correct

Comment: It is very uncommon to vote down a correct answer. Anyway, I am going to  correct answer and if you don't like me, tell me. I will fix it for you.

Comment: sorry, I upvoted it, and then tried to remove my upvote, which apparently turned it into a downvote :(

Comment: anyway I put my upvote back, because I am feeling kind

Comment: Much better. Explains the reasoning behind it. See my answer below, as well.

Answer (score 1):

`text-align: center` will make the text *inside* your object (table, div, etc) centered.

`margin: 0 auto` will center the object itself within the page.

So the one you require is `margin: 0 auto;` (the auto is the one which centers the object, the 0 is the top and bottom margin).

And given the structure of your code, the margin: 0 auto; needs to be applied to the table, not its parent div.

```
table {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You also don't need `<a name="table"></a>` because you can use the `id="table"` as the anchor.

Comment: Hiya ! @AHBagheri I really appreciate for you making an effort to correct me. Also I have tried margin:0 auto; as well but to no avail unfortunately. Please see this link. Thanks. https://codepen.io/Donnie-D/pen/gmmwyR

Comment: the problem is that the default styling for `div`s is 100% width, so the table is left-aligned within the div. I have edited my answer to match.